# Using ansible core's pip and virtualenv on Centos or Redhat

Tags: python, django, centos, vagrant, ansible

I have created a playbook that is suppose to run a django website for local developers. These are organizational constraints

- Currently the VM is Centos - http://puppet-vagrant-boxes.puppetlabs.com/centos-64-x64-vbox4210.box
- The machine is being provisioned with ansible via Vagrant.
- The developer will need python2.7.

I attempted to follow the software collections route in

- adding a scl repo to box
- installing python27 via yum
- using shell modoule to enable python27
- creating a virtualenv inside that shell

The newly create virtualenv and python binaries give an error after provision. Here is the pertinent part of my playbook:

### main.yml

```
- hosts: app
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: root
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    # insert other roles
  tasks:
    - name: Add SCL Repos
      command: sh -c 'wget -qO- http://people.redhat.com/bkabrda/scl_python27.repo >> /etc/yum.repos.d/scl.repo'
    - name: Install python dependencies
      yum: pkg={{ item }} state=present
      with_items:
        - "python-devel"
        - "scl-utils"
        - "python27"
    - name: Manually create virtual .env and install requirements
      shell: "source /opt/rh/python27/enable && virtualenv /vagrant/.env && source /vagrant/.env/bin/activate && pip install -r /vagrant/requirements/local.txt"
```

### Ansible - stdout

Here is the tail end of my ansible's stdout message.

```
pip can't proceed with requirement 'pytz (from -r /vagrant/requirements/base.txt (line 3))' due to a pre-existing build directory.\n location: /vagrant/.env/build/pytz\nThis is likely due to a previous installation that failed.\npip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this.\nPlease delete it and try again.\n\nCleaning up...
```

### Post Mortem Test via SSH

In an attempt to glean more information out the problem, I sshed into the box to see what feedback I could get.

```
$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Fri Feb 12 22:17:03 2016 from 10.0.2.2
Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cd /vagrant/
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ source .env/bin/activate
(.env)[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ pip install -r requirements/local.txt
/vagrant/.env/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In general, the approach feels like a square peg in a round hole. I'd love to hear some feedback from the community about the appropriate way to run a centos box locally using a python27 virtualenv provisioned through ansible.

Comment: If you're creating a VM entirely to run a single application why do you need virtualenv? Virtualenv is brilliant for a development machine that is running multiple applications that needs different library versions but otherwise you're just adding a small layer of complication to your build

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I wanted to isolate python environments in the standard method, which is virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use ansible environment directive to manually set appropriate variables so that correct executables get called. Here's an example:

```
 environment:
    PATH: "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64"
    MANPATH: "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/share/man"
    XDG_DATA_DIRS: "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/share"
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/pkgconfig"

  pip: "virtualenv={{root_dir}}/{{venvs_dir}}/{{app_name}}_{{spec}} requirements={{root_dir}}/{{spec}}_sites/{{app_name}}/requirements.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to rebuild python from source to create a python2.7 virtual environment. I used an open source playbook.

- https://github.com/Ken24/ansible-role-python

### main.yml

```
- hosts: app
  roles:
    - { role: Ken24.python }
  tasks:
    - name: Install virtualenv 
      command: "/usr/local/bin/pip install virtualenv"
    - name: Create virtualenv and install requirements
      pip: requirements=/vagrant/requirements/local.txt virtualenv=/vagrant/cfgov-refresh virtualenv_command=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```